How can I use Python to send CAN XCP messages to a measurement ECU?
I need to use Python to implement the MEASUREMENT and CALIBRATE features for an ECU using the CAN XCP protocol. I already have an A2L file to declare variable names corresponding to ECU addresses. I want to read and write variables at those ECU addresses.
I have reviewed the PyXCP library but could not find any examples. How should I use this library to meet my requirements?
